# why e.Keychar is not working in keypress event?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem regarding the KeyChar `e.KeyChar`. It is not working. I want to get the value of e from, please have a look and your comments are highly appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub txtTax_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
             ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtTax.KeyPress
        If (Strings.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 0) Then
            Try
                If (Me.conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
                    Me.conn.Open()
                End If
                Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(("Select * from TaxGroup where TaxName='" & Me.txtTax.Text & "'"), Me.conn)
                Dim dataSet As New DataSet
                adapter.Fill(dataSet, "TaxGroup")
                Me.dgrdTax.DataSource = dataSet.Tables.Item(0)
                Me.dgrdTax.Visible = True
            Catch exception1 As Exception
                ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1)
                Dim exception As Exception = exception1
                Interaction.MsgBox(exception.Message, MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, Nothing)
                ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: "it is not working." - and that means?

Comment: Google "Little Bobby Tables"

Answer (score 2):

Your event declaration is wrong.  The correct signature is:

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) 
                                Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
```

`KeyChar` is not a part of `EventArgs`, which is largely just a base class.

I am guessing maybe your thought you needed to type it in yourself.  Just pick the control from the left drop down and the event from the right and the IDE will create it for you.  I am not sure how that could happen otherwise.

Comment: honest mistake? or too much beer? neither: another randomUserName?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        Dim allowedChars As String = "1234567890" ' allowed In textbox
        If Not allowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString.ToLower) Then
            e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
```